# is there a quick exact way to connect two cylinders with different size?

Tags: mesh

I have this two cylinders and I want to connect them to one part.

So I want a plane to lay down on their surface (or just connect them) so that they touch only the surface/tangent of the cylinder like pic2.

Is this somehow easy and exact possible?

my current solution is: i use a plane and try to lay it like i want to find the exact face i need to bridge the faces. But i cannot believe that such a great tool like blender hasn't a better solution than this. (pic3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: select faces. right-click and click on bridge-faces

Comment: if i select faces and do bridge-face the error appears: select at least 2 edge loops

Comment: ah, sorry, it wasn't one object - my mistake

Comment: that is one part of the solution, thank you Mohammad. But how do i know the tangent face? I tried also with face snapping...but did not work at all

Comment: you should select faces you need to connect. its up to you.

Comment: i know, but i asked whether there is a quick exact way to do it. I didn't meant manually.